# ZF: How to get current url on any page in the view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, url

I have a value in general layout. 
I need to set this value to current url on any page.
How to do this?

Thanks to all

Comment: Try to be more accurate on what you want, and post some code.

Comment: Sorry for my English. It solved it by $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] temporarily. I needed to get $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] via ZF in the view;

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are few ways you could get the requested url. One is through `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, as you did, but off course ZF has its own ways. Two examples are:

```
  // you can call it in a view or a layout
  $uri = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();

  // or using userAgent view helper in a view or a layout:
  $uri = $this->userAgent()->getServerValue('request_uri');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 42):

In **Zend Framework 2** you can use Zend\View\Helper\ServerUrl view helper. It's very simple:

```
//for example, your current URI is: http://mydomain.com/page/sample/

//get your domain
$uri = $this->serverUrl(); // Output: http://mydomain.com

//get your current URI
$uri = $this->serverUrl(true); // Output: http://mydomain.com/page/sample/
```

Learn more: http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/create-full-urls-in-zf2-views

Comment: Yes, you are right but it seems for ZF2. The question was for ZF1 and ZF2 didn't exist in 2011-)

Comment: @Anthony I didn't saw that, sorry:) But I found your question while searching how to do the same in ZF2:)

Comment: ZF1 has this implementation too. Look at Zend_View_Helper_ServerUrl, it does the same.

Answer (score -3):

In ZF1 and ZF2 you can use the Url View Helper with null to get the current route

`<?= $this->url() ?>`

Comment: It returns only part of the url, without action or other parameters. Question was about current url, not only route.